# Limit row number in <li> tag to a specific number

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

I need to make a list that looks like this

```
item1  item4  item7
item2  item5  item8
item3  item6
```

currently I am using this particular code using `<ul>` and `<li>` tag:

```
<ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
   <li>item4</li>
   <li>item5</li>
   <li>item6</li>
   <li>item7</li>
   <li>item8</li>
   <li>item9</li>
</ul>
```

is there any way to limit the row number to specific value (in this case 3) and if the data exceed that specific value, the list will continue in the next column? I read `column-count` properties of CSS3, I also wonder if there is also `row-count` properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this layout using a flex box approach.

You set the ul to have a height of 3 times the li, and the rest is automatic

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
   <li>item4</li>
   <li>item5</li>
   <li>item6</li>
   <li>item7</li>
   <li>item8</li>
   <li>item9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you,but i wonder if flexbox is supported on older browsers?

Comment: Have a look at [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for browser support.

Comment: It seems that flexbox is not supported on some older browsers, so i'm afraid i cannot use this for my current project, but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is impossible without Javascript.

If you are open to a Javascript solution then here is how I would do it :

```
var maxRow = 3;
var lis = $("#myList li").length;
var cols = Math.ceil(lis / maxRow) + "" ;

if (cols > 1)
  for (var i = lis; i <  (maxRow * cols); i++) 
    $("#myList").append( '<li class="noBullet">&nbsp;</li>' );

$("#myList").css( { 'columns' : cols,
                    '-webkit-columns' : cols,
                    '-moz-columns' : cols } );
```

With this simple css rule :

```
.noBullet {list-style-type: none;}
```

This script build a grid based on the `maxRow` you specify.  It appends invisible `<li>` to the list to make sure the first columns are always filled up.

You can have a look at the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kad7g4uf/126/).

Comment: Glad I could help but vals solution seems much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine in Chrome, and IE 11

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 4em;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
   <li>item4</li>
   <li>item5</li>
   <li>item6</li>
   <li>item7</li>
   <li>item8</li>
   <li>item9</li>
</ul>
```