# Displaying angular 6 material radio buttons dynamically in multiple columns

Tags: angular, layout, radio-button, angular-material

How is it possible to display dynamic Angular Material radio buttons on multiple columns, like in the following picture:

[image: Example of radio buttons on multiple columns]

From the possible options, I tried using `mat-grid-list`, as the docs says it automatically calculates how many rows it will have. However, this doesn't work.

```html
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-grid-list cols="3">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let radioBut of objectlist">
      <mat-radio-button [value]="radioBut">
        {{radioBut.label}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: i didnt get what is your problem exactly

Comment: I have a list of radio buttons as input, which I have to display in multiple columns. I can display horizontally or vertically easy in one row or column, but I did not see how to display on multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, not sure you can achieve that with the Angular Material grid system, but you could use CSS with the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let radioBut of objectlist">{{radioBut.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

And in your CSS file :

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 4em;
}
```

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988026/7575207) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, it is ok also with CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```html
<mat-radio-group>
 <mat-grid-list cols="3">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let radioBut of objectlist"
   [colspan]="1">
   <mat-radio-button [value]="radioBut">
    {{radioBut.label}}
   </mat-radio-button>
 </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

You'll have 4 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I can see the radio buttons in multiple columns. There is still one thing which I did not mention, as I thought is clear (sorry- my mistake): the order of the buttons  is important, that is first column needs to be generated, then the second one, so that Radio2 is underneath Radio1, Radio3 under Radio2